# How to run code periodically in android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In my android project, I want to run an async task every 30 seconds. I implemented my own chat system, and I want to check for new messages every 30 seconds.

Basically, I want the code to run no matter which activity is running.

So I was thinking on the main menu activity which will always be there if the user is using the app since I don't finish activities when I make new ones. However the code should still run even when I open a new activity.

Also the code should stop when the app is closed. I'd prefer if the code still ran if the app was minimized but that isn't required. I plan to display notification icons on the top bar.

How can I do this in Android?

Comment: AsyncTask won't work for you, as it's tied to the activity that started it.  Instead use a Service.

Comment: Can you show an example of it?

Comment: The pattern seems wrong to me. A lot of battery and network drain for no real gain. This would greatly annoy me as a user and lead me to uninstalling the app. Use sockets or push notifications instead.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at ScheduledExecutorService. It's exactly what you need. In this example It will run your method to check for new messages every minute.. 
Remember to add the proper permissions to your manifest for background services.

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduleTaskExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);

// This schedule a runnable task every minute
scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {

  public void run() {

checkNewMessages(); // your method to check for messages here

}
    }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES); // you can also uses seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

You should start a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html). While the service is running you can call [startForeground()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29) to add the notification that you want. Now, while the service is running you need to call the asynctask every 30 seconds. One option is to create a Handler and call [postDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) which will call your asynctask. After you asynctask completes (success of failed), recall the postDelayed. When the app closes you can unbind or call stopService.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions, you can start an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) to run which does its work in the background. After doing all of the work in onHandleIntent, you can reschedule it run again in 30 seconds using [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

HOWEVER, polling every 30 seconds for a chat application is a terrible idea. You will kill the user's battery unneccessarily. Use Push Notifications instead.